# How do I calculate $x^\nu$ using the below definition?

Tags: special-relativity, vectors

In Einstein's Theory of Special Relativity, the four-vector ($x^\mu$) of an object is given below in Equation $1$, and the conversion between the inverse of the four-vector and $x^\nu$ is in Equation $2$. I am wondering how to divide $x_\mu$ by $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, and obtain a vector, instead of a tensor. An in-depth explanation of how to come to that conclusion would be appreciated, if possible with this question.

$1: x^\mu=\left(ct,\vec{x}\right)$

$2: x_\mu=x^\nu \eta_{\mu\nu}$

Comment: What do you mean by "the inverse of the four-vector"? Do you really mean the co-variant vector that corresponds to the contra-variant vector?

Comment: $x_\nu = \eta_{\nu\mu}x^\mu$, where there is a summation convention. Is this what your Eq 2 is supposed to be? Is there an implied summation in your Eq 2?

Comment: @hft, when, in my question, I said "the inverse of the four-vector", I did actually mean the covariant vector that corresponds to the four-vector, or, as you stated it, the contra-variant vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just divide by the metric like that because there's an implicit summation due to the Einstein Summation convention.

$x_\mu = \eta_{\mu\nu} x^\nu = \sum_\nu \eta_{\mu\nu} x^\nu$ where $\eta_{00}=-1$ and $\eta_{11}=\eta_{22}= \eta_{33}=1$.

For example,

$x_0 = \eta_{\mu\nu} x^\nu = \sum_\nu \eta_{\mu\nu} x^\nu= \eta_{00} x^0+ \eta_{01}x^1 +\eta_{02}x^2 +\eta_{03} x^3 = -x^0 +0+0+0=-x^0$

$x_1 = \eta_{\mu\nu} x^\nu = \sum_\nu \eta_{\mu\nu} x^\nu= \eta_{10}x^0+ \eta_{11}x^1 +\eta_{12}x^2 +\eta_{13} x^3 =0+ x^1 +0+0=x^1$